Apisix on Kubernetes: is it possible to deploy Apisix without the Database support (Standalone mode)?
TL;DR
I'd like to know if it's possible to deploy Apisix on a Kubernetes cluster, without the Database support (etcd), via Helm.
If it's possible, how do I need to configure the Helm chart values?

Long Version
Base Setup
My setup is based on minikube and I'm using the apisix/apisix Helm chart.

Start a minikube cluster:

minikube start --driver=docker


Run minikube tunnel and leave it running in a separate terminal:

minikube tunnel


Install Apisix:

helm repo add apisix https://charts.apiseven.com
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm repo update

kubectl create ns "ingress-apisix"

helm install apisix apisix/apisix --namespace "ingress-apisix" \
  --namespace ingress-apisix \
  --set service.type=LoadBalancer \
  --set ingress-controller.enabled=true \
  --set ingress-controller.config.apisix.serviceNamespace=ingress-apisix

NB: I'm using a LoadBalancer for easier route testing on localhost (that's why I'm using minikube tunnel)
What I Tried
I noticed from the documentation that there's a "Standalone" deployment mode which:

will no longer use the default etcd as the configuration center.

And is suitable for Kubernetes users due to:

Declarative API that dynamically updates the routing rules with a full yaml configuration.

However, when I tried to deploy Apisix with what I think are the necessary config values, the installation gets stuck:

File values-dbless.yaml (values from apisix/apisix Helm chart):

apisix:
  deployment:
    mode: standalone
    role: "data_plane"

etcd:
  enabled: false

service:
  type: LoadBalancer

ingress-controller:
  enabled: true
  config:
    apisix:
      serviceNamespace: ingress-apisix
      adminAPIVersion: v3


Install Apisix with the following command:

helm repo add apisix https://charts.apiseven.com
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm repo update

kubectl create ns "ingress-apisix"

helm install apisix apisix/apisix --namespace "ingress-apisix" \
  -f "./values-dbless.yaml"


It doesn't start the etcd pods anymore, but the apisix-ingress-controller Pod is forever stuck waiting for the wait-apisix-admin InitContainer, which spams the following log messages:

waiting for apisix-admin
waiting for apisix-admin
waiting for apisix-admin
waiting for apisix-admin


Additional Info/Resources

GitHub issue: doc: fix standalone mode FAQ


Maybe using Bitnami's Helm chart: bitnami/apisix
